# c# json deserialization complex objects

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have a problem deserializing a json file, this is the json:

```
[
    {
        "id": "id", 
        "number": "48", 
        "date": "17-01-2020",
        "details": [
            {
                "id": "id",
                "code": "code",
                "description": "desc"
            },
            {
                "id": "id",
                "code": "code",
                "description": "desc"

            }
        ],
        "address": "add",
        "note": null 
    },
    {
        "id": "id",
        "number": "55",
        "date": "17-01-2020",
        "details": [
            {
                "id": "id",
                "code": "code",
                "description": "desc"
            },
            {
                "id": "id",
                "code": "code",
                "description": "desc"
            }
        ],
        "address": "add",
        "note": null
    }
]
```

this is my code:

```
 var result = httpClient.GetAsync(".....").Result;
 List<Docu> doc= new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Docu>>(result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

class Docu contains definition of id, number, date, details and:

```
public List<Details> det{ get; set; }
```

Class Details contains id, code and description definition

I can deserialize everything except complex object details, it returns null from deserialization, how I can fix this? I need to fill the list of details

Comment: Can you show us the complete class? Maybe some properties have only getters, that is a common issue, you need to have both getters and setters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have wrong name for `List<Details>` property

it should be

```cs
public List<Details> details{ get; set; }
```

according to json you have shown